# How to unlock drive that has been locked by Windows 10 fast start up from outside windows

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery, liveusb, win10-fast-startup

I have been using this windows 10 laptop that used my credentials from my former workplace to log in (it's not a managed computer though). Today those credentials expired and I'm trying to access some files I didn't back up.

I tried mounting the windows drive from an ubuntu live usb, however I can't even see the internal drive. From this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1121676/cant-see-internal-drive-when-using-ubuntus-liveusb I feel it's due to the fast startup settings that have locked the drive.

Is there a way to unlock it so I could access it from the live usb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**N.B.** Before doing anything, though, make a disk image, e.g. using a [Macrium Reflect](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) Rescue USB drive. If things go badly, you can recover your data from that. Actually, you can even use Reflect to mount that image, making all data availbale.

You can also [mount a drive with a Ubuntu Live USB *read-only*](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/mount-ntfs-linux), even if it's "dirty", i.e., has Fast Startup files on it. Actually, you can even force it to be mounted *read-write*, but that is *not*- advisable, as you might not easily be able to use it to run Windows again.

Though you can easily do this from Terminal, similar to Windows "CMD prompt," you can use *gparted*, a GUI for *parted*, to do so.

- Create the [Ubuntu Live USB](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) drive. Version 20.04 LTS or later is suggested.
- If [*gparted*](https://itslinuxfoss.com/how-to-install-and-use-gparted-on-ubuntu-20-04/) is not installed on the USB, install it:

  - Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to run Terminal.
  - Type (or paste, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> ) `sudo apt install gparted`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and enter `y` if asked to proceed.
- Find the internal disk, click on the main NTFS partition, and mount it, read-only.

You should be able to read all data, even in locations Windows would have locked. Of course, *none of this will work on an encrypted drive,* but you did not state encryption such as BitLocker was in use.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I will try  that. And thanks for the tip about making a disk image before anything, hadn't thought of that.